# Plot ROC curve with pROC R

Tags: r, plot, roc

I build a text classifier with randomForest, so to evaluate it I try to create a ROC curve with pROC pâckage .

Here the code :

```
ndsi.forest <- randomForest(tf.idf[train.index, ], as.factor(train$Note.Reco[train.index]), ntree = 100)

#predict with test data
ndsi.pred <-predict(ndsi.forest, newdata = tf.idf[test.index, ], response  = 'class')
pred <- data.frame(ndsi.pred)
result <- data.frame(id = Data_clean$id[test.index], sentiment = pred[ , ])

##"ROC curve"
multiclass.roc(result$sentiment, test$Note.Reco)
```

I was wondering if is teher a way to create the plot? ROC plot with pROC package?

I try with this code :

```
roc(test$Note.Reco, result$sentiment, levels = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

But I get this error :

```
Error in roc.default(test$Note.Reco, result$sentiment, levels = c(1, 2,  : 
  'levels' argument must have length 2
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Have you used `plot.roc` function? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pROC/pROC.pdf

Comment: To represent a `roc` curve, you need two vectors: the first one referring to the response variable (a factor with two levels) and the second one, a continuous variable indicating the predicted values for each sample. Additionally, you can specify which are the labels of your first argument. They are only two, because the first input is a dichotomous factor. So, how does `test$Note.Reco` look like?

Comment: Ah ok, my response variable is a vector of value from 0 to 10, how can I do in this case? :/

Comment: I have `result$sentiment : Factor of 11 levels "0,1,..10"` and `test$Note.Reco : int 6 3 6 7 8 10 0 1 2`  How can I do i this case? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I have understood, you have a **multiclass response variable** (corresponding to 10 different groups).

The ROC - curve is defined for the classification of two groups, so what multiclass makes is to compute the classification for "***one group against the rest***". `multiclass.roc` function doesn't allow you to represent the curves, but understanding what it does, you can:

**1)** Consider as many roc curves as groups you have. That is, the ROC - curve for the classification of:

- Group 1 vs Not Group 1
- Group 2 vs Not Group 2
- . . .
- Group 10 vs Not Group 10

You can do that with the `roc` function. The only thing you need is to redefine the response vector with 1 for the individuals belonging to the group i and  a 0 for the rest of individuals. Save each `roc` object with a differnt name.

**2)** To represent all the curves, just use `plot` function for each of the curves adding `plot(..., add=T)` to all of them but the first.

Comment: Not quite correct. The multiclass in pROC tests every possible pair of group: 1 vs 2; 1 vs 3; 1 vs 4; ... 9 vs 10. So many more ROC curves actually.

Comment: Thus, you need to get 90 curves, and for that you need to make subset of individuals containint one of each pair of responses (let's call them `i` and `j`.